# Transparency bug IE11

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, transparency, internet-explorer-11

IE 11.0.9600.17690 update KB3032359 on some computers shows inappropriate transparent areas in response to keyboard input in elements formatted with the bootstrap3 form-control class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rendering bug triggered by the use of transparency with the box-shadow attribute used by bootstrap to place a blue halo around the focused control. It can be resolved by adding the following class override.

```
.form-control:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,255,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,255,1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,255,1);
  border-color: #888;
}

.form-control:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,255,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,255,1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,255,1);
  border-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

The key difference from the bootstrap style is the alpha channel is set to 1 (no transparency). It doesn't look *quite* as polished as it does with transparency, but it doesn't trigger the bug.